# Execute step in TeamCity ONLY if previous step was failed

Tags: selenium, teamcity

I have 3 steps in my build. If third step failed, I need to run specific step, which have to run ONLY after fail of previous one. How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like there's an execution policy to "run on previous step failure". You could work around it by using the execution policy "even if some of previous steps failed" and having your particular build step handle the logic.

i.e. If previous step successful, do nothing. If previous step unsuccessful, do the failure case.

If you need to detect if previous step was a failure or not, you could consider making a part of your build creating a status file (if `in_error` file exists then perform your task)

Answer (score 0):

I was surprised that TeamCity does not support it out of the box in 2021. But API gives you a lot usefull features and you can do it

As a solution you need to write bash script and call TeamCity API inside

1. setup API key in MySettings & Tools => Access token
2. create env variable with API token
3. create a step in your configuration with Execute step: Even if some of the previous steps failed
4. build own container with jq or use any existing container with jq support
5. place this bash script

```
    #!/bin/bash
    set -e -x
    
    declare api_response=$(curl -v -H "Authorization: Bearer %env.teamcity_internal_api_key%" -H "Accept: application/json" %teamcity.serverUrl%/app/rest/latest/builds?locator=buildType:%system.teamcity.buildType.id%,running:any,canceled:all,count:2\&fields=build\(id,status\))
    
    declare current_status=`echo ${api_response} | jq '.build[0].status'`
    declare prev_status=`echo ${api_response} | jq '.build[1].status'`
    
    if [ "$current_status" != "$prev_status" ]; then
            do you code here
    fi
```

some explanation of code above. with API call you get 2 last builds of current buildType. This is last build and previous build. After you assign variable with statuses and compare them in if statement. If you need to run some code in case of current build failed use

```
if [ "$current_status" = "FAILURE" ]; then
    write your code here
fi
```